# Mouse events with child Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have an issue with mousemove (and any kind of other mouse events) and a child iframe.

When i click on iframe and then drag mouse over the main frame, mousemove event of main frame simply does not fires.

I've tried to bubble events to the parent (but this way i can't get event.target)

I've tried to use HTML5 DND but there is a problem with performance. It works well, but generates strange HitTests (in chrome).

Ideally i want to make it with mousedown+mousemove.

I've made a simple demo of this problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xr1f03do/31/)

```
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");

var frameBody = frame.contentDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
frameBody.innerHTML = "CLICK HERE AND DRAG OVER THE BOXES TO SEE THE PROBLEM. Why parent's listener makes nothing?";


frame.contentDocument.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    console.log("frame mousedown");
})



document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {

    // I need it working here with all event properties like event.target of the main fame
    console.log("main move");
  var resultBox = document.getElementById("result");
  if (event.target.id)  resultBox.innerHTML = event.target.id;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/xr1f03do/33/

```
frame.contentDocument.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("frame mousedown");
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine with the way you have it. If I load an url into the iframe it doesn't work as expected. I am unable to capture events.

Comment: Yes, that's may be the problem in your case